# Maximize JInternalFrame event

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

InternalFrameListener does not implement the method of InternalFrame State Change.
I was wondering to know that if any event can be implemented to check if the JInternalFrame  is maximized or not?
If yes,then how?

Comment: *"If yes,then how?"*  Perhaps a better questions is: Why (do you think you need to know)?  Use layouts properly and let them take care of component (re)positioning and sizing.

Comment: @  Andrew Thompson I am sorry I din get you and I have used my layout properly and as far as answer is concerned I guess it can be done via PropertyChangeListener..EDIT: ya its accomplished..

Comment: Great! If you've solved you can add your answer and auto accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it can be done via

EDIT:

```
        PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener = new PropertyChangeListener()     {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            JInternalFrame[] jInternalFrame=desktop.getAllFrames(); //desktop is JDesktopPane
            if(interFrame.isMaximum()){
            System.out.println("My window Maximised");
            }};

      interFrame.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener );
```